# TestLink1.9.12 Cannot export report in excel format

Tags: testlink

I used Testlink 1.9.12 at Report and Metrics on Report format the dropdown for **"MS excel"** and **"MS Word"** is disappear while i test on TestLink 1.9.7(Ghost). The dropdown is appear

You can test in this link below 1.9.13 is appear to be the same 
http://demo.testlink.org/latest/index.php

Do you guy have any idea is that a bug or wrong configuration

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found it in the change of this version the excel has been removed from dropdown box and use it as a small icon on the top of report item as the small green excel icon